# categorical data normalization in SVM Classification

Tags: categorical-data, svm

I have a set of features (contineous + categorical)...I have converted the different categories to numerical, for example (object1, object2, object3) = (1,2,3)..etc. and ran SVM...

I obtain high SVM performance in this way.

Are the results I obtained considered wrong since I have not binarized the categorical data as it is advised frequenly.

Comment: Probably, but it's hard to say. Can you add more information to clarify your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a factor to a vector of integers imposes a structure upon it. You are making the assumption that the levels are ordered (and in the order corresponding to the integers used) and that the difference between each level is the same. If this assumption is reasonable then you've got a smaller number of predictors and things might work out well. If this assumption fails miserably, as it often will, then you've replaced a potentially useful feature with a less useful feature.

You can always try both ways and see what happens.

Consider linear regression: $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$. Suppose that $X_1$ is a factor with $k$ levels. If we represent it by a single vector containing numbers in $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$ then we will get a single coefficient $\beta_1$ for its effect. This means that if all else is held constant going from $X_1 = 1$ to $X_1 = 2$ changes our estimate of $E(Y)$ just as much as going from $X_1 = k-1$ to $X_1 = k$. If instead we encode $X_1$ by $k-1$ indicator variables then we'll get $k-1$ different $\beta_j$ corresponding to each one so that each level can have an entirely different effect.